# How to set <li> Background color?

Tags: css, background, html-lists

I believe it's simple, but since I'm new to this I don't have a clue of how to do it.  I just want to change the background color of a li tag - just for fashioning, nothing else.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul id="abas">
     <li><a href="#tab1">PROGRAM</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">PROC</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">DDNAME</a></li>
</ul>
```

Sorry for being a noob but, this is the css part right?

```
#abas li a
{
text-decoration:none;
background-color:3B31FF;
color:#FFFFFF;
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
border-top-left-radius:23px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px; 
-moz-border-radius-topright:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius-topleft:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius-topright:5px;     
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px; 
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius-bottomleft:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius-bottomright:5px;  
padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 100px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

I noticed that here>>>  "background-color:3B31FF;" is where I change the 
color of the background, but doing this, changes all the background colors of course
... I only need 1 "li" tab to change and any html tutorial would be nice too.

Comment: Here's the clue : use CSS. This clue is valid for all the styling you might want on any item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First any css color code needs to have **# followed by a 6 digit value**(or 3 if they are repeating i.e #FF33FF as #F3F) and to solve your second part do this

**CSS**

```
#abas li { 
    background-color:  #xxxxxx ;
    //your other style goes here
}
#abas li.current { 
    background-color:  #xxxxxx ;
    //your other style goes here
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="abas">
     <li class="current"><a href="#tab1">PROGRAM</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">PROC</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab3">DDNAME</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: oh well, i REALLY tough that this one would work but something weird happened, when i finished typing the code, it created a "wrap" around,  blue inside(was already blue) and green outside (the "li.current" color set, and of course i also placed all the other css style, just changed the background color.

Comment: should i have deleted something?

Comment: ha, make some changes and i guess i can use these code pretty well, thanks, and to any other one that tried to help, seriously, just saved my bacon.....

Answer (score 2):

**Css code:**

```
#abas li { 
 background-color:  ... ;
}
```

fill in color code where dots are, like this:

```
background-color:#000000; //color black
```

Single tag:

**Css code:**

```
li.selected { 
     background-color:  ... ;
    }
```

**Html code:**

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li class="selected"></li>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I really aprecciate the quick answer but i might have missed something, I need to change only one tag.

Comment: works, and does not work, sorry for the troubles, and I also posted the css code (hope it helps)

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color simply style it:

```
<li style="background-color:blue;">Program</li>
```

You will likely also want to set some height and width parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the first item have a red background:

```
<li style="background: red"><a href="#tab1">PROGRAM</a></li>
```

Comment: Maybe its better for new people to direct learn them to use a css sheet instead of inline coding..

Comment: Maybe. Using a CSS sheet was a not part of the question, and my code is complete, will work in-place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to for example add green to a `<li>` tag you can do the following:

```
<li style="background: green;"><a href="#tab1">PROGRAM</a></li>
```

But this isn't really best practice because normally you want to keep your HTML and CSS separated. So in CSS you would do it like this:

```
li { background: green; }
```

or use [hex color codes](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colorsfull.asp):

```
li { background: #00ff00; }
```

---

If you only want to change one specific `<li>` tag you can add a class to it:

```
<li class="precious">
```

and then apply a css rule to this class:

```
.precious { background: #00ff00; }
```

and only this `<li>` tag with the .precious class is going to get styled.

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pulleasy/WEdmt/

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your life a whole lot easier with the border-radius element. for what you are doing it would be:

```
#abas li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: 3B31FF;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    border-radius: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

This will give you the same result. Also for example sake, you will need to add a height and a width to get some sort of result. so if that were the case you would need to do this:

```
#abas li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: 3B31FF;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    border-radius: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px; 
}
```

This will give you the result that I think you were looking for. If you are looking to use pixels instead of percents for a fluid layout, the you will need to use this. (Note this is only for the width, height and positioning).

```
#abas li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: 3B31FF;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 20px; 
    border-radius: 23px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    width: 10%; /*Replace these percentiles with your width and height*/
}
```

I will assume that you know how to make the

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using hex code is using RGB / RGBA:

```
background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

This gives you even more control over your color by adding alpha and transparency support, but unfortunately, it's not supported by some browsers (IE, namely, although I don't know about IE 10).